# Fade Transitions

Tags: iphone, animation, transition

I have a bit of code that i use to transition between views.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mainSprite.frame, backTopPathImg.frame)) {
    levelOneViewController * levelOne2 = [[levelOneViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:levelOne2 animated:NO];
    [levelOne2 changeSpriteLocationTopPath];

}
```

This makes a regular transition where it just cuts to the other view. My question is how could i make this a fade transition? As in a long fade through black. Keep in mind i am not using a navigation controller, just #importing the view controller then using the above code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `modalTransitionStyle` property of [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Try the following

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mainSprite.frame, backTopPathImg.frame))
{
    levelOneViewController * levelOne2 = [[levelOneViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    levelOne2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:levelOne2 animated:YES];
    [levelOne2 changeSpriteLocationTopPath];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a UIView with a black background laid over top of your `levelOne2` and over time change the `opacity` of it from 1.0 to 0.0.

Here is a similar question: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12998-how-fade-between-views-transitioning-through-black.html